# PyQGIS - Saga Channelnetwork

Tags: pyqgis, saga

I am trying to run this from QGIS python console to extract the channel network from the DEM, based on the catchment area:

```
processing.runalg('saga:channelnetwork', 'C:/Data/filled.tif', None, 'C:/Data/catchment_area.tif', 2, 10000000, None, 10, None, 10, 'C:/Data/channel_network.tif', 'C:/Data/africa/channel_route.tif', 'C:/Data/channel_network.shp')
```

The output is empty with nan values.

This is how I have derived the catchment area:

```
import processing
processing.runalg('saga:fillsinks', "C:/Data/clipped.tif", 0.010000, "C:/Data/filled.tif")
processing.runalg('saga:flowaccumulationtopdown', 'C:/Data/filled.tif', 0, 'C:/Data/catchment_area.tif')
```

I am using QGIS 2.18.11 with SAGA 2.3.2

Comment: What values are you getting in catchment_area.tif? Try lowering the threshold if your values are lower

Comment: Thanks. The issue was with the projection not the threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a projection issue and by changing from the coordinate system to projection system, it worked well.

Here is the link for the solution from SAGA forum: 
[SAGA Forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/354013/thread/1426f9e5/)

Comment: Please mark your question as answered.